# Mapping Oracle bool fields with nHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, mapping

I have an Oracle database and the boolean fields are CHAR(1) with Y/N stored. How can I map this to a bool type using nHibernate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set type="YesNo" in the nhibernate property definition for the field.

For more info, see table 5.3 in [this doc](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html) which maps .NET types, to DB types.